# Links in Tables - fonts mess up table alignment

Tags: fonts, org-table

I would like to use links in a table to explain certain entries more in depth.

```
| Some | random | table | entries |
| More | data   | and   | LINK      |  <- misaligned

* LINK target with 
 - more info about this line
 - explained in more details
```

But when I use links inside of a table, the fontsizes dont match and the table misaligns. Characters are either `org-table` or `org-link` formatted and both faces have different font sizes.

How could I solve this?

I don't see a way to define a special `org-link` face inside of `org-table`.

Comment: Can't you use a fixed-width font? This is the only completely reliable solution that I know of.

Comment: Hi Nick, I do use a fixted-width font, but `org-table` and `org-link` have different font sizes in their face settings. I tweaked the link face to fit to the regualr text. The table face is not modified atm.

Comment: By default, these faces inherit everything and just modify some attributes (foreground color, underline etc). So they should not have different font size: you can verify with `emacs -q` - does the problem still exist? If not, then find the place where you customized them and get rid of the font size change.

Answer (score 1):

Try [valign](https://github.com/casouri/valign).
This package solves several aligning problems in org-mode, with one issue that currently incompatible with `org-indent-mode`.

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising! Will try and accept if it works.

Comment: It works on small tables, but I was not able to switch cells with TAB anymore. For my larger table it took ages, so I had to kill emacs after 5 mins of no response. It's a good aproach, but maybe there is something more "native" which works with larger tables, too.